# How to install Subversive offline

Tags: eclipse, svn, rad, subversive

I want to install Subversive in my RAD/Eclipse. How can I install it **offline**?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *offline*? Do you want to run your own SVN on your computer?

Comment: I mean i don't want to connect the update site of Subversive. I want to download the needed files and install offline

Answer (score 17):

Browse to the following site:

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php

Look for a link labeled "archived updated site" that is appropriate for your Eclipse version. Download to your system.

In the Install New Software dialog, select Add and use the Archive option to point to the zip you've downloaded. You will also want to disable the "contact all update sites during install..." option. At this point you should be able to install Subversive without Eclipse accessing the network.

Comment: it needs a connector like JavaHL or similar. The only way to add that library is again internet

Comment: This worked for me, my problem was that I hadn't disabled the "contact all update sites during install..." option. Thanks